# is it possible to inject a custom claim into an OAuth2 access token?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

The customer scenario is the following:

1. Both App1 and App2 are registered in the same tenant
2. App1 uses client credentials flow to request an (app-permission) access token
   for App2.
3. AzureAD is the Identity Provider

This customer is looking for a way to inject a custom claim (something like “my cool claim”: “xyz”) in the access token.  This custom claim is only consumed by App2.

I have looked at both optional claims docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) and the custom claims mapping policy docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping) and don’t see anything that can cater towards this scenario where there is no User involved.

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Comment: and why do you think it is not possible? Have you tried it before asking a super generic question with no sign of any effort proving one or other thing?

Comment: If you think this is possible please point to the documentation and specific section and I will be happy to try this out.  I have experimented with both optional claim and claim mapping policy but have not found anything yet.   The claims mentioned in those docs are more for the User object getting a delegated token.  There is no login user for this case.  It's an app-only token.

Comment: (1) because in simple service-to-service scenario you do not really need custom claims. (2) because you can use [application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) to provide more fine grained control in service-to-service security. (3) StackOverflow is not a place to ask where to find proper documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on application roles.  This might work with 'application' allowedMemberTypes.  It's customer's requirement to inject custom claims in their service to service scenario and to be clear, I am not asking to find the documentation specifically.  I am just asking for idea/input to see if this can be done and how.